# How to say this in English?

Tags: word-usage

How to say in English "a bunch of coriander plants or fenugreek plants or any other bunch of leafy vegetables bunch which we see at greengrocer?

2.Is there any other name for the hard peel of ground nut or almond in English?

Comment: It would be best if you asked just one question per post. If someone does a great job answering your first question, but doesn't answer your second question well, it makes it difficult to decide whether to up-vote or down-vote the answer. There is some good advice for asking questions in this post on meta: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4785/9161

Answer (score 1):

Description in question: hard peel of ground nut or almond.

Nuts have shells or hulls, not peel. Bananas, apples etc. have **skins** which can be **peeled**. When you peel them, those are peelings. **Banana peelings**. Those can be fed to pigs, for example.

**Nuts have shells or hulls**. **Nuts are sold shelled and unshelled or hulled and with hulls.**

Hulling and Drying

"Nuts have an inedible outer hull (also called a husk, shuck, or bur) that you must remove promptly after harvest so the nuts can dry properly." [the hull is also called a shell]

**Careful with the term ground nuts. Groundnuts (like peanuts) ripen underground.**

Whereas: **ground nut means the *nut has been ground*, a verb. To grind nuts. Grind (infinitive and present), ground (simple past), ground (present perfect, etc).**

**Leafy (usually) green vegetables are just called that, and include: spinach, kale, lettuce, for example.**

Coriander also known as cilantro is not called "a vegetable" in English. **Cilantro and other spices like dill or parsley are called herbs in English.**

[hulls](http://homeorchard.ucdavis.edu/8005.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The proper word to use when talking to a greengrocer (or anyone else) is *bunch*.

> I would like a bunch of parsley and a bunch of carrots.

[Oxford dictionary online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bunch):

> Bunch: A number of things, typically of the same kind, growing or fastened together.

On the other hand, *bunch* isn't always the best word to use for every vegetable; we would probably ask for a *head of lettuce* or a *stalk of broccoli*. (Although *bunch* should be understood, even in these cases.)

Comment: Yes, also bunches of herbs such as fenugreek and cilantro. Though one is hard pressed to find fresh fenugreek.